# How to parse html in Japanese with lxml and produce readable output?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml, lxml.html

I have been using Beautiful Soup and in BS4 it does a wonderful job by simply doing

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding='Shift_JIS')
```

it will print out the whole html nicely in Japanese if I try to print in my terminal and output into files.

```
<p>PR検索</p>
```

I have tried an equivalent approach in lxml by reading other people's question

```
tree = etree.HTML(res.txt, parser=etree.HTMLParser(encoding='shift-jis'))
```

however,it displays everything in unicode.

```
<p>PR&#26908;&#32034;</p>
```

I tried the following as well, but the result is the same

```
tree = etree.HTML(what.text, parser=etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

I have used an alternative to use lxml.html to parse the page first and then send to BS4 to get the encoded result that I want, however I would still like to know how to get the correct output without BS4, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is working for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import fromstring, HTMLParser


data = """<p>PR検索</p>"""

tree = fromstring(data, parser=HTMLParser(encoding='shift-jis'))
print etree.tostring(tree, encoding='shift-jis', method="html")
```

prints:

```
<p>PR検索</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that does work! So in lxml, you need to specify the encoding for both parsing and printing?